# Mapping a list in hibernate by ordering instead of an index-field

Tags: hibernate, list, collections, mapping

This works:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Train" table="Trains">

        <id column="id" name="id" type="java.lang.String" length="4">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="trips" cascade="all">
            <key column="trainId"/>
            <one-to-many class="Trip"/>
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But my trips are all naturally ordered by their `scheduledDate`. I would like to replace the `Set` with a `List`. Changing the collection to:

```
        <list name="trips" cascade="all" order-by="scheduledDate">
            <key column="trainId"/>
            <one-to-many class="Trip"/>
        </list>
```

does not work, since it now requires an `<index/>`. I don't want to add an index to my table, because *the ordering is given by the date*.

Any way this can be done? Or should I just get the `Set` from Hibernate, and then sort it myself in code? Seems unnecessary when we already have it ordered by the DB.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually, this can be done with `<bag>`, `<set>` or `<map>` mappings. `<bag>` uses `java.util.List` semantics but does not maintain element indexes. By specifying it's `order-by` attribute, its elements will be ordered as part of SELECT:

```
<bag name="trips" cascade="all" order-by="scheduledDate">
    <key column="trainId"/>
    <one-to-many class="Trip"/>
</bag>
```

Note that `order-by` attribute needs to specify **column** name(s), not property name. The above can be mapped to `java.util.List`, you can do the same with `java.util.Set` by using `<set>` mapping. No need for comparators :-)

Details are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted)

Comment: The posted link now gives a 404. Should be http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-sorted

Answer (score 0):

I realized that using a `List` is not the correct way to store a collection of naturally ordered items.

The solution is to use a `SortedSet` (like a `TreeSet`) with a `Comparator`.